# Parse a string by Lexing.from_string

Tags: parsing, ocaml, lex, lexical-analysis

I have implemented [this example](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual026.html#toc110), and it works well.

Now, I want to read from a string instead of reading from `stdin`, so I change the `calc.ml`:

```
let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string "1+3" in
    let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
    print_int result
  with Lexer.Eof ->
    print_string "Lexer.Eof";
    exit 0
```

And oddly, it returns `Lexer.Eof` as result. If I remove `| eof { raise Eof }` from `lexer.mll` and , it tells `Fatal error: exception Failure("lexing: empty token")`. I guess something is wrong around `end-of-input` condition... Does anyone know how to change the lexer so that it could lex a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the EOL:

```
let _ =
  try
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string "1+3\n" in
    let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
    print_int result
  with Lexer.Eof ->
    print_string "Lexer.Eof";
    exit 0
```

**EDIT**

Or if you do not want to add the EOL:

In `parser.mly`, add the token `EOF` and:

```
| expr EOF                    { $1 }
```

In `lexer.mll`, not raise eof but return the token `EOF`:

```
| eof            { EOF }
```

And finally, `calc.ml`:

```
let _ =
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_string "3+1" in
    let result = Parser.main Lexer.token lexbuf in
    print_int result
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work. But I want to parse a normal sting without EOL. I have changed to `main: expr { $1 };` in `parser.mly`, oddly with `"1+3"` it still returns `Lexer.Eof`, does `Lexing.from_string` accepts only string ending by `"\n"`?